# search a multiple file with the exact date then tar and log

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have a simple problem.. First I searched a multiple file named "HAHAHA-1, HAHAHA-2, HAHAHA-3"(just an example) with the exact date last 2 days ago. Then I will tar them. This is my sample script and it is running..

```
 stat -c"%z;%n" * | grep "`date +%Y-%m-%d -d '2 days ago'`" | grep "HAHAHA-*" | awk -F';' '{ print $2 }' | xargs tar -zcvf TAR_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d' --date='2 days ago').tar.gz
```

Now my problem is how can I add this script to save it also into a log file?

```
LOG-$(date '+%Y_%m_%d' --date='2 days ago').log
```

Example:

```
tar -ztvf TAR_2014_02_01.tar.gz
```

Output:

```
HAHAHA-1
HAHAHA-2
HAHAHA-3

vi LOG-2014_02_01.log
```

Output:

```
HAHAHA-1
HAHAHA-2
HAHAHA-3
```

Any Ideas? Thank You!

Comment: What do you want to put into this log file?

Comment: yes sir. I will tar then save it also into a log file. I will put also all the "HAHAHA-*" files. into a log file.

Comment: You want to save content of tar into log file OR just 1 line in log file that some tar file has been created?

Comment: I want to save all the content of tar into log file.

Comment: Thank You so much sir! I just add &> then log script. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do tar -tvzf and redirect its contents into a log file.

```
dt=$(date '+%Y_%m_%d' --date='2 days ago')

tar -tvzf "TAR_${dt}.tar.gz" > "LOG-${dt}.log"
```

Comment: Thank You. I just add &> LOG-$(date '+%Y_%m_%d' -d '2 days ago').log